# Linq Grouping based on other keys and values table

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I have two Entities `ItemChange` and `PK`:

```
[Table("Sync_Changes")]
public class ItemChange
{
    public Guid AgentId { get; set; }

    public DateTime ChangeTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Descriminator { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public object Item { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<PK> PKs { get; set; }

    public virtual ChangeType State { get; set; }
}
```

And the PK class:

```
[Table("Sync_PKs")]
public class PK
{
    public PK(string key, object value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value?.ToString();
        ValueType = value?.GetType().Name;
    }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Change))]
    public Guid ChangeId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ValueType { get; set; }

    public virtual ItemChange Change { get; set; 
 }
```

I want to group the `ItemsChange` based on the PKs, for example i have two ItemChange that have the Pks [({Key="Id",Value="1"},{Key="GroupId",Value="2"})]
and the ChangeType [Created,Updated].

i want to know how to do this with Linq, or Mysql Script. 
Screenshots of the both tables:
Changes that i want to group theme base on the pks.
[image]
PKs

[image]

Comment: are you using code first ?

Comment: yes, i use Code First.

Comment: i'm not following a lot you have `changetype` one to many --> `PK` how can a `PK` have many `changetype`s

Comment: its a journal of changes the PK table just store the PKs of an object  of type Descriminator that changed by the changeType.

Comment: i mean what's the selector in `pk` that has many `changetype`s , i see  table `PK` has changeId that's one-to-one with change, AgentId and valuetype only have few values ,,, that makes the only logical selector the column `value` am i right ?

Comment: no the Key its may multiple primary keys(Id,GroupId,...), i want to group the changes of a descriminator in a period time by the PKs values.